# Is it possible to add a column to a temp table (using alter) and then immediately update that column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wondering if I can take an already created temp table (for the purpose of this exercise let's assume that I cannot simply add anything to it within code) and add a column using ALTER and then UPDATE that newly created column? Something like this

```
 create table #test (first int, second int)

 insert into #test (first, second) values (24,8439)
 GO

 alter table #test ADD SymCount [uniqueidentifier] NULL
 GO

 update #test
 Set SymCount = (Select distinct count(first) from #test)

SELECT * From #test

drop table #test
```

It's clearly not recongizing `SymCount` as a column when I'm attempting to update... is this just not supported or am I doing something wrong? Any insight as to why, and how I can create a workaround would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Im guessing you actually want (Select count(distinct first) from #test) btw...

Comment: As dan indicated, you need to switch SymCount to be an int rather than a uniqueidentifier since quids and ints do not play well with each other.  I'm not sure how valuable that would be though.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you're setting int to uniqueidentifier. Check the following code :

```
drop table #test
go

 create table #test (first int, second int)

 insert into #test (first, second) values (24,8439)

 GO

 alter table #test ADD SymCount [uniqueidentifier] NULL

 GO

 insert into #test select 1,1,newid(); -- works

 update #test
 Set SymCount = (Select distinct count(first) from #test) -- you can't do that - syntax error : Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier. Int can't be set to uniqueidentifier

SELECT * From #test

drop table #test
```

Comment: Will this not simply create a new row? Is it possible to use an UPDATE on the newly created 'SymCount'

Comment: Yes, it'll create a new row. And yes, you can do an update too but you need to pass uniqueidentifier to the uniqueidentifier column.

Answer (score 1):

SQL2008 - Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier.

'1' is not going to work as a uniqueidentifier value. Try changing [uniqueidentifier] to [int]

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx :

"Uniqueidentifier is a 16-byte GUID that can be initialized to a value in the following ways:

1. By using the NEWID function.
2. By converting from a string constant in the form xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, in which each x is a hexadecimal digit in the range 0-9 or a-f. For example, 6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF is a valid uniqueidentifier value."

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed datatypes.  You are trying to assign an integer to a uniqueidentifier field.